# Ubuntu sub system not seeing .htaccess

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an ubuntu sub system for windows 10, it doesn't seem to be able to see .htaccess when doing ls, nor does apache execute the instructions. However, if I put anything before the . it then sees it, but no point there since that wont work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Edit your question, it is not very clear, if there is any question...

Answer (score 0):

Im an idiot, didnt realize I forgot to allow overrides in apache config, and sub system requires the -a to show the . files.

For anyone who has same issue:
Got to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Change Allowoverride None to Allowoverride All under the apache Directory settings for /var/www/html
Service apache2 restart

To show the file when inside a directory ls -a